# Component Lifecycle (ComponentDidMount) not working when moving tab in TabBar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I move the page using the library `react-native-tab-navigator` of these navigators to move the `componentDidMount` page it can only be done once and after that, the lifecycle component does not work, ask for the solution: following my code.

I have opened an issue on Github, I have tried sending the state to the parent. I have used

> react-native-tab-navigator version 0.3.4

```
class MainTab extends Component {

state = {
    selectedTab: 'home'
};

render() {
        return (

                <
                TabNavigator.Item selected = {
                    this.state.selectedTab === 'home'
                }
                title = "Home"
                selectedTitleStyle = {
                    {
                        color: "#FF7158",
                    }
                }
                tabStyle = {
                    {
                        borderTopWidth: this.state.selectedTab === 'home' ? 3 : 0,
                        borderTopColor: '#FF7158',
                        backgroundColor: this.state.selectedTab === 'home' ? '#fff8f6' : '#FFFFFF'
                    }
                }
                renderIcon = {
                    () => < Image source = {
                        require('allComponents/images/ic_beranda.png')
                    }
                    style = {
                        {
                            width: 18,
                            height: 18
                        }
                    }
                    />}
                    renderSelectedIcon = {
                        () => < Image source = {
                            require('allComponents/images/ic_beranda-actives.png')
                        }
                        style = {
                            {
                                width: 18,
                                height: 18
                            }
                        }
                        />}
                        // renderBadge={() => <View style={{width: 20, height:20, backgroundColor:'#FF7158', borderRadius:50}}><Text style={{fontSize:12, textAlign:'center', color:'white', fontWeight:'600'}}>2}
                        onPress = {
                            () => this.setState({
                                selectedTab: 'home'
                            })
                        } >

                        <
                        /TabNavigator.Item> <
                        TabNavigator.Item
                        selected = {
                            this.state.selectedTab === 'profile'
                        }
                        title = "Pemesanan"
                        selectedTitleStyle = {
                            {
                                color: "#FF7158",
                            }
                        }
                        tabStyle = {
                            {
                                borderTopWidth: this.state.selectedTab === 'profile' ? 3 : 0,
                                borderTopColor: '#FF7158',
                                backgroundColor: this.state.selectedTab === 'profile' ? '#fff8f6' : '#FFFFFF'
                            }
                        }
                        renderIcon = {
                            () => < Image source = {
                                require('allComponents/images/ic_pemesanan-inactive.png')
                            }
                            resizeMode = 'stretch'
                            style = {
                                {
                                    width: 18,
                                    height: 18
                                }
                            }
                            />}
                            renderSelectedIcon = {
                                () => < Image source = {
                                    require('allComponents/images/ic_pemesanan-active.png')
                                }
                                resizeMode = 'stretch'
                                style = {
                                    {
                                        width: 18,
                                        height: 18
                                    }
                                }
                                />}
                                onPress = {
                                    () => this.setState({
                                        selectedTab: 'profile'
                                    })
                                } >

                                <
                                /TabNavigator.Item> <
                                TabNavigator.Item
                                selected = {
                                    this.state.selectedTab === 'riwayat'
                                }
                                title = "Akun"
                                selectedTitleStyle = {
                                    {
                                        color: "#FF7158",
                                    }
                                }
                                tabStyle = {
                                    {
                                        borderTopWidth: this.state.selectedTab === 'riwayat' ? 3 : 0,
                                        borderTopColor: '#FF7158',
                                        backgroundColor: this.state.selectedTab === 'riwayat' ? '#fff8f6' : '#FFFFFF'
                                    }
                                }
                                renderIcon = {
                                    () => < Image source = {
                                        require('allComponents/images/ic_akun-inactive.png')
                                    }
                                    resizeMode = 'stretch'
                                    style = {
                                        {
                                            width: 18,
                                            height: 18
                                        }
                                    }
                                    />}
                                    renderSelectedIcon = {
                                        () => < Image source = {
                                            require('allComponents/images/ic_akun-active.png')
                                        }
                                        resizeMode = 'stretch'
                                        style = {
                                            {
                                                width: 18,
                                                height: 18
                                            }
                                        }
                                        />}
                                        onPress = {
                                            () => this.setState({
                                                selectedTab: 'riwayat'
                                            })
                                        } >

                                        <
                                        /TabNavigator.Item>

                                    );
                                }
                            }
```

I expect that `componentDidMount` can function on TabBar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` won't trigger when it is inside a tabNavigator (expect for the first time the component gets mounted).

The reason is that when switching from a tab to another, every tab gets rendered a first time, leaving all the tabs rendered without unmounting them.

I don't know which navigator you are using, but usually you have a way to know when a screen gets 'focussed' and when it gets 'blurred'. Using those you can trigger a function when you have the screen passing from blurred to focussed.

Comment: Can you give examples

Comment: You have an example in the documentation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/function-after-focusing-screen.html#triggering-an-action-with-a-didfocus-event-listener